# Break table horizontally into two or more lines based on page margins

Tags: tables

I'm typesetting some tables that are long in the horizontal direction. I would like to break the table when it reaches the end of the line, and continue it on the next line—like in a `longtable`, but in the other direction.

A common example I might have is a table like this:

[image]

Currently, the way I handle this is to break this into two lines, so that the margins are respected.

```
\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllll}
    kon     &   pi              &   nimi    &   akesi   &   li          &   ni:     &   ona     &   li          &   ken &   lon &   ma      &   sama    &   soweli,         \\
    spirit  &   \textsc{regr}   &   word    &   reptile &   \textsc{pr} &   this    &   they    &   \textsc{pr} &   can &   at  &   land    &   like    &   land\_animal    \\
\end{tabular}\\
\begin{tabular}{lllllll}
    taso    &   ona     &   li          &   jo      &   e               &   linja   &   ala.    \\
    but     &   they    &   \textsc{pr} &   have    &   \textsc{obj}    &   hair    &   not     \\
\end{tabular}
```

I would instead prefer to have the table be written as one piece:

```
\begin{tabular}{llllllllllllllllllll}
    kon     &   pi              &   nimi    &   akesi   &   li          &   ni:     &   ona     &   li          &   ken &   lon &   ma      &   sama    &   soweli,         &   taso    &   ona     &   li          &   jo      &   e               &   linja   &   ala.    \\
    spirit  &   \textsc{regr}   &   word    &   reptile &   \textsc{pr} &   this    &   they    &   \textsc{pr} &   can &   at  &   land    &   like    &   land\_animal    &   but     &   they    &   \textsc{pr} &   have    &   \textsc{obj}    &   hair    &   not     \\
\end{tabular}
```

Is there a way to do this without separating the table into two `tabular`s and having to choose the line break manually?

Comment: oh i have that redefined because i use it so often that saving 4 characters is a huge timesaver. i will edit the examples so that they don't distract from the actual issue.